# How to efficiently find a dictionary value based on another value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large (~100k) list of dictionaries:

```
[{'sequence': 'read the rest of this note', 'score': 0.22612378001213074, 'token': 3805, 'token_str': 'note'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this page', 'score': 0.11293990164995193, 'token': 3674, 'token_str': 'page'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this week', 'score': 0.06504543870687485, 'token': 1989, 'token_str': 'week'}]
```

Given a `token` ID (e.g `1989`), how can I find the corresponding `score` in an efficient way? I have to do this multiple times for each list (I have several of these large lists and for each one I have several token IDs).

I'm currently iterating through each dictionary in the list and checking if the `ID` matches my input ID, and if it does I'm getting the `score`. But it's quite slow.

Comment: Can we assume that the token IDs are unique across all dicts?

Comment: If by unique you mean that there is one unique token for each `token_str` in that large list, then yes. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: I mean that there are no duplicate values for the `'token'` key.

Comment: Yes, there are no duplicate values. You can think about this list of dictionaries as an unordered list having each token with a value of `1-100k` (given that the length of the list is 100k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have to search multiple times maybe create a single dictionary with the token as the key:

```py
a = [{'sequence': 'read the rest of this note', 'score': 0.22612378001213074, 'token': 3805, 'token_str': 'note'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this page', 'score': 0.11293990164995193, 'token': 3674, 'token_str': 'page'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this week', 'score': 0.06504543870687485, 'token': 1989, 'token_str': 'week'}]

my_dict = {i['token']: i for i in a}
```

It would take some time to create the `dict` but after every search would be `O(1)`.

This might seem inefficient but python handles memory in a very efficient way, so instead of creating the same dictionary already on the `list` on the new `dict` it actually holds a reference to the `dict` already constructed on the list, you can confirm that using:

```py
>>> a[0] is my_dict[3805]
True
```

So you can interpret that as creating an aliases for each element in the list.

Comment: Nice. I'll wait to see if there's a slightly more efficient way to do this, but this looks good

Comment: It does look like it's creating `my_dict` pretty quickly. How would you find the score of `token = 3805`? I'm not too familiar with dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: It return a dict with all the values, you can get the `score` with `my_dict[3805]['score']` if you're sure you'll only use the score from that token you create my_dict by using `{i['token']: i['score'] for i in a}` and you'll be able to access it directly: `my_dict[3805]`

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas might be more efficient for large datasets.

An example for finding the score with the token 3805:

```py
import pandas as pd

source_list = [{'sequence': 'read the rest of this note', 'score': 0.22612378001213074, 'token': 3805, 'token_str': 'note'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this page', 'score': 0.11293990164995193, 'token': 3674, 'token_str': 'page'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this week', 'score': 0.06504543870687485, 'token': 1989, 'token_str': 'week'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(source_list)
result = df[df.token == 3805]

print(result.score.values[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list of dictionaries is:

```py
l = [{'sequence': 'read the rest of this note', 'score': 0.22612378001213074, 'token': 3805, 'token_str': 'note'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this page', 'score': 0.11293990164995193, 'token': 3674, 'token_str': 'page'}, {'sequence': 'read the rest of this week', 'score': 0.06504543870687485, 'token': 1989, 'token_str': 'week'}]
```

And the values of `token` you are interested in are, for example:

```py
token_values = [1989, 30897, 98762]
```

Then:

Build a dictionary as follows:

```py
d = {the_dict['token']: the_dict['score']
    for the_dict in l where the_dict['token'] in token_values}
```

This will build a minimal dictionary containing just the key values you are interested in with their corresponding scores.